# How to get string value of a "selected_node" in a treeview row?

Tags: python, kivy, treeview

I am working with a treeview and I would like to know the value of the result of "selected_node"
in text or string but when I click in a row, I have only "<kivy.uix.treeview.TreeViewLabel object at 0xc3f3f508>"

Could someone explain to me how to do this?

Comment: Try adding `.text` to the selected node.

Comment: thx... @John Anderson ! it's works !